# Web Browser Turbo C++

Tags: c++, browser, dev-c++, turbo-c++, bgi

So I was browsing the Internet for a project and stumbled upon this piece of code. It runs perfectly until the point you enter a website(include "www" :P) and press Enter and then boom! The program terminates, no error message, nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize_graphics_mode();
int get_key();
void draw();

union REGS i, o;

main()
{
  int key, i = 0, xpos, ypos, button;
  char arr[200], temp[5], *ptr;
  char a[] = "C:\\Progra~1\\Mozill~1\\firefox ";

  strcpy(arr,a);

  i = strlen(a);

  initialize_graphics_mode();

  draw();

  while(1)
  {
    if(kbhit())
      key = get_key();

    if((key>=97&&key<=122)||(key>=65&&key<=90)||key==46||key==47||key==63)
    {
      arr[i] = key;
      sprintf(temp,"%c",arr[i]);
      outtext(temp);
      if(getx()>470)
      {
    clearviewport();
    moveto(5,2);
      }
      i++;
    }
    else if ( key == 13 )
    {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      system(arr);
      break;
    }
    else if ( key == 27 )
    {
      closegraph();
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    if(button==1&&xpos>=150&&xpos<=480&&ypos>=300&&ypos<=330)
    {
      system("C:\\Progra~1\\Mozill~1\\firefox programmingsimplified.com");
      break;
    }
    key = -1;
  }

  closegraph();
  return 0;
}

void initialize_graphics_mode()
{
  int gd = DETECT, gm, errorcode;

  initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");
  errorcode = graphresult();

  if( errorcode != grOk )
  {
    printf("Graphics error : %s\n",grapherrormsg(errorcode));

    printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
    getch();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

int get_key()
{
  i.h.ah = 0;
  int86(22,&i,&o);

  return( o.h.al );
}

void draw()
{
  settextstyle(SANS_SERIF_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,2);
  outtextxy(275,11,"Web Browser");
  outtextxy(155,451,"<a> href=http://www.programmingsimplified.com"">www.programmingsimplified.com</a>");
  outtextxy(5,105,"Enter URL : ");
  rectangle(120,100,600,130);
  setviewport(121,101,599,129,1);
  moveto(5,1);
}
```

Could someone help me in understanding why this happens? and possibly a fix for this?

NOTE: + It is supposed to work if you have Mozilla Firefox. If you have  any other browser, please edit the code accordingly.

- I am running this on Turbo C++, what would I have to do in order to convert this code for Dev-C++?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I'm new to C++ so elaborate as much as possible.

Comment: Step 1: Uninstall Turbo C++ Step 2: Install a modern IDE / compiler

Comment: but...graphics.h doesn't work in dev-c++(orwell). And, my school isn't open to a change in compiler! fml @CoryKramer

Comment: Turbo-C++? The compiler from 1992?

Comment: Apparently, no student in my school has never even asked for a compiler change @Borgleader

Comment: If you are Windows, you can suggest that IT install [Visual Studio 2015 - Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx). It is a free full-up IDE and compiler. Tell them the nice people on Stack Overflow suggested it will help your learning.

Comment: @Kshitij Be that student! \o/

Comment: @Borgleader I did! Anyways, if they change it, its cool but until then I gotta stick with turbo and this code is for turbo C so, it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @CoryKramer hahaha I told them something similar,"Stack Overflow suggests that the compiler you use sucks" and as I said I gotta stick with Turbo until they change it, so any solutions for turbo c++?

Comment: `I gotta stick with Turbo until they change it,`  After 23 years, no change?  `It is supposed to work if you have Mozilla Firefox`  You are using 20th century technology in attempting to open 21st century websites.

Comment: Hopeless, I know. So I can't build something even close to a browser then? Drop this idea? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: You are really not creating a browser.  All that code seems to be doing is calling FireFox and plugging in a website to open.  The `system` call is still available, and I think this is all you're really doing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand that and I just wanted to see the use of the system() function but the problem always seems to be about how old this compiler has become

Comment: @Kshitij: Indeed. The biggest problem here is that `system` asks the Operation System to do something (hence the name of the function) but Turbo C++ assumes that the OS is MS-DOS. Windows 95 still had a copy of MS-DOS 7.0 internally, but since XP it's entirely faked.